# Change custom title bar height in code for specific screens

Tags: android, android-titlebar, custom-titlebar

I want to set custom title height in code in begining of Activity life cycle insted of doing it in the styles section.

```
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,
                            R.layout.customtitlebar);
```

Now I want to set height atttribute.

The reason is that I want certaing titles to contain more data then others.